# Consultar RestApi externa no XamarinForms

Tags: api, xamarin-forms, cross-platform

estou tendo dificuldade para realizar uma consulta em uma RestAPI externa da TinyERP para consultar e incluir pedidos via um app criado na minha empresa, algumas dificuldade é usar o json pois sou novo no xamrin e em um aplicação asp.net framework esta funcionando corretamente.
Segue o model de criado no json2csharp:

```
 public class Pedido2
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string numero { get; set; }
        public object numero_ecommerce { get; set; }
        public string data_pedido { get; set; }
        public string data_prevista { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public double valor { get; set; }
        public string id_vendedor { get; set; }
        public string nome_vendedor { get; set; }
        public string situacao { get; set; }
        public string codigo_rastreamento { get; set; }
        public object url_rastreamento { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pedido1
    {
        public Pedido2 pedido { get; set; }
    }

    public class Retorno
    {
        public string status_processamento { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string pagina { get; set; }
        public string numero_paginas { get; set; }
        public List<Pedido1> pedidos { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Retorno retorno { get; set; }
    }
```

e segue a page.cs:

```
    using MacVendas.Models.API;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using static MacVendas.Models.API.Pedido;

namespace MacVendas.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProdutoPage : ContentPage
    {

        public ProdutoPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Iniciar();
            this.BindingContext = new Pedido();
        }
        private void Iniciar()
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var resp = client.GetAsync("https://api.tiny.com.br/api2/pedidos.pesquisa.php?token=""&formato=json").Result;
            string respStr = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            RootObject ObjContactList = new RootObject();
            if (respStr != "")
            {
                //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list  
                ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(respStr);
            }
            //Binding listview with server response    
            listviewConacts.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.retorno.pedidos;
        }

    }
}
```

e a page.xmal:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Text="JSON Parsing" FontSize="25" />
        <ListView x:Name="listviewConacts" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="listviewContacts_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding numero}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding }" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                            <BoxView HeightRequest="2" Margin="0,10,10,0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ProgressLoader" IsRunning="True"/>
</Grid>
```

desde já agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade que você está tendo? Copiei seu código aqui e o objeto `ObjContactList` é preenchido corretamente na conversão do Json.

Comment: Então quando eu tento visualizar a lista não aparece nada na minha page xaml, ela fica em branco

Comment: O problema está no `binding` da `ListView` que não está pegando a propriedade `pedido.nome` e assim por diante. Se puder, edite o título da sua pergunta por favor, para ajudar na pesquisa de outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dados não estão sendo exibidos no `ListView` por que faltou colocar a hierarquia do objeto que você quer exibir, como por exemplo: `objeto1.objeto2.propriedade`.

Neste caso a classe `Retorno` tem uma lista `List<Pedido1> pedidos` e cada item `Pedido1` tem um objeto do tipo `Pedido2`, e por sua vez o objeto `Pedido2` tem todos os dados de `Pedido` como `nome` e `numero`.

O `ListView` está recebendo uma lista de `Pedido1` da classe `Retorno`

```
listviewConacts.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.retorno.pedidos;
```

só que na view o `binding` está como `{Binding nome}` e na classe `Pedido1` não existe a propriedade `nome`:

```
<Label Text="{Binding nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

Os atributos do pedido (nome, numero e etc.) estão todos na classe `Pedido2` que por sua vez é uma propriedade da classe `Pedido1`.

**Correto:** colocar no `binding` da `ListView` o nome da propriedade da classe `Pedido1` (propriedade `pedido`) que é do tipo `Pedido2`.

```
<Label Text="{Binding pedido.nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<Label Text="{Binding pedido.numero}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: Agora o problema é que o listview termina antes de ver todos os item